# Programming 3D shapes without any libraries in Java

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I was wondering if there is any simple code examples or guides on creating a 3D rectangle in Java without using any 3D libraries like Java3D or OpenGL!

Comment: _creating a 3D rectangle in Java without using any 3D libraries like Java3D or OpenGL_ but why?

Comment: You are going to have to explain a little more a 3D rectangle is just 6 points in space.

Comment: Are you asking for how to write a renderer? There are plenty of sources for that... most in C++ but it would not be hard to translate... Or maybe you are asking for a software render library -- I doubt that exists/ has significant support since it doesn't make sense to do in many contexts

Comment: www.java-examples.com/draw-3d-rectangle-square-applet-window-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3D Rectangle is called a rectangular prism.

Defining a 3D shape isn't very difficult.  Here's one definition of a rectangular prism.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class RectangularPrism {

    protected Point3D originPoint;
    protected Point3D xPoint;
    protected Point3D yPoint;
    protected Point3D zPoint;

    public RectangularPrism() {

    }

    public RectangularPrism(Point3D originPoint, Point3D xPoint, 
            Point3D yPoint, Point3D zPoint) {
        this.originPoint = originPoint;
        this.xPoint = xPoint;
        this.yPoint = yPoint;
        this.zPoint = zPoint;
    }

    public void setOriginPoint(Point3D originPoint) {
        this.originPoint = originPoint;
    }

    public void setxPoint(Point3D xPoint) {
        this.xPoint = xPoint;
    }

    public void setyPoint(Point3D yPoint) {
        this.yPoint = yPoint;
    }


    public void setzPoint(Point3D zPoint) {
        this.zPoint = zPoint;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g, Point3D viewPoint) {

    }

    public class Point3D {
        protected int x;
        protected int y;
        protected int z;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getZ() {
            return z;
        }

        public void setZ(int z) {
            this.z = z;
        }

    }

}
```

It's creating that render method that takes some calculation.  And that calculation would be different for every 3D shape you want to define.

Your calling routine would have to figure out the order in which to render all of your 3D shapes.  basically, the furthest 3D shapes have to be rendered first, so that the closer 3D shapes overlap properly.

A 3D library not only has all of this figured out, it is also optimized so that a 3D scene can be rendered in the shortest amout of time possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.awt.Graphics.draw3DRect() method.
http://www.java-examples.com/draw-3d-rectangle-square-applet-window-example.

Comment: this is not 3D rectangle but only a rectangle with 3D like effects (shadow etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented simple viewer which you can download at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14767221/projection.7z